# How to display number count with a restrict number count of 255? Similar to Twitter, and without using Max length?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, character, countdown, onkeyup

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

function showComment(count){ 
  //get the length of the comments. use document.getElementById.comments.length 
  let length = document.getElementById("showComment").length;
  //find the characters left by subtracting 255 - length 
  //condition if we go over 255
  //disable the field or just make the value equal to the first 255 characters. We can use substring method 
}    
    
</script>    
    
    
</head>
<body>

<form action="" method="post">    
<input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname"  placeholder="fullname"><span class="err"></span><br>
<div id ="showcomment" >You have <span id="numleft"></span> characters of your 255 left!</div>        
<textarea id="comments OnKeyUp="showComment()></textarea>  
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enter"> 
    </form>
</body>    
</html>
```

I'm trying to display the characters I have left. I only have a total of 255 letters to spare and it should stop at 0. Also, I'm not suppose to use maxLength method.

Answer (score 1):

Read the `value` of the `<textarea>` element to access what was entered.

```js
document.getElementById('comments').addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  e.target.value = e.target.value.substring(0, 255); // cut off at 255 chars
  document.getElementById("numleft").textContent = 255 - e.target.value.length;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" placeholder="fullname"><span class="err"></span><br>
<div id="showcomment">You have <span id="numleft"></span> characters of your 255 left!</div>
<textarea id="comments"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enter">
```

Comment: 0



255 - e.target.value.length;

Can you explain to me what is happening? 255 is the total amount minus the length of what? I'm having a hard time visualizing it.

Comment: @NathanVu `e.target` is the `<textarea>` element. The `value` of the textarea is the string that was input in it. The length of that string gets you how many characters were entered.

Comment: Got it. I see that it's taking 255 minus the current input, when you minus the input length it's printing our the current number. Makes sense! Also, when I'm typing it all the way through it is counting to -1, not 0?

Comment: @NathanVu My mistake; I had the statements in the wrong order. The updated code fixes that.